# Getting all weeks days label in user language

Tags: java, android, date

I would like to do something more clever than:

```
String[] strDaysEn = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
String[] strDaysFr = new String[] { "Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi" };
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="week_days">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Tuesday</item>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I would like to do that automatically in my user langage, and getting the benefit of java and Date, so basically I would have to do a loop with:

```
for (i= 0 to 6)
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(new Date()+i);
    System.out.println(date);
```

This would be really better because java.Date will give me all translations automatically! ANd I of course do not want to reinvent the wheel!

But this loop seems a waste of time and processor, and I am sure, there is a better way to achieve this.

Thank a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the [day names from the Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) of the language that you need, without using any formatter in between. You shouldn't let the translators of your app do work which has already been done in the framework.

```
String[] days = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getWeekdays();
```

Comment: Above approach will return this : [, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]. That is , No of days is 8. Why is it so ?

Comment: because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924231/dateformatsymbols-getshortweekdays-returning-weekdays-count-as-8

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a good way to solve this for multiple languages.
Have a look at [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) and [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).
This allows you to specify language dependend files into different XML resources. Android will automatically pick the correct one depending on the users device locale.

You could write these days into a [`<string-array />`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) inside `res/values/strings.xml` for your main/fallback language. To provide the translations, just create alternative resources. E.g. for french, create a folder `values-fr` and save the french `strings.xml` into `res/values-fr/strings.xml`.

Here is a sample array in a resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="week_days">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Tuesday</item>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You can receive this array in code via

```
String[] days = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.week_days);
```

*(`week_days` is the string-array name in this example)*

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, I edited my question: of course, I know: res/values-fr/strings.xml. But What what I would like to do is getting the benefit of java and Date, so I don't have to write all strings myself. That's not that I am lazy, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Ah ok, well can't help you there. You have to provide all the other strings anyway, don't you? Otherwise you end up with mixed language in your app, and that looks usually not great imho (I'm currently on my linux mint box with an english/german mixed menu - not pretty).

Comment: mhhh, yes, you are right... Am av very curious and I would like to see the answer to my question, the only way I can thank you is to vote for your answer..